# save button not working in table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have code in which adds the rows in clicking add.The addition of rows works well but after that save button not works.I use JavaScript For that but no control transferred to that code on click of save button.

```
      <?php
  include_once("noaccess.php"); 
  include_once(CLASS_PATH."fetch_service.php"); 
  $objfetch = new fetchService();
  include_once(CLASS_PATH."update_service.php"); 
  $objupdate = new updateService();


  ?>
  <!--  -->
  <div class="dashboard">
      <h2>Update Extension</h2>
      <?php
      $result = $objfetch->fetch_ext("decode(password, '\$VarahaMVC\$') as password,id,firstname,","where `account_id`='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' ORDER BY `id`");
      $i = "1";
    echo   $cnt = sizeof($result);
      if ($cnt == $row3['num_of_lines']){
      echo '<span style="color:#df0909;text-align:center;"><h3>Maximum Extension Limit Reached.</span></h3>';

      }
      ?>

      <!--**
          ** EDIT EXTENSION
          *-->
      <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['msg'])){?>
  <div class="msg">
      <span><?php echo $_COOKIE['msg'];setcookie("msg","",time()-5,"/");?></span>   
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <?php }?>

  <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['err'])){?>
  <div class="err">
      <span><?php echo $_COOKIE['err'];setcookie("err","",time()-5,"/");?></span>   
      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <?php }?>

      <div id="umcloader" style="float:left;"></div>

      <form name="frmextension" id="frmextension" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="hid_mode" value="<?php echo $mode;?>" />
      <table id="tblext" class="tbl_altcolor shadow" style="width:98%;margin-left:20px" align="left">
      <thead>
          <tr align="center" bgcolor="#999999" height="25">
          <th width="8%">Name</th>
          <th width="6%">Extension</th>
          <th width="8%">Password</th>
          <th width="8%">Confirm Password</th>
          <th width="8%">number</th>


          </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody style=" border-collapse:collapse">

      <input type="hidden" name="case" id="case" value="update_ext" />

      <?php

          foreach($result as $row)
          {
      ?>
          <tr align="center">
              <td width="8.5%">
                  <input type="hidden" name="hid_extid[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="hid_extid<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
                  <input type="text" name="fname[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="fname<?php echo $i;?>" class="input required" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="<?php echo $row['firstname'];?>" style="width:80% !important" />
              </td>

              <td width="85px">
                  <?php echo $row['ext_number'];?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="ext[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="ext<?php echo $i;?>" class="input required digits extvalue" placeholder="Enter Extension" value="<?php echo $row['ext_number'];?>" style="width:80% !important" />
              </td>

              <td width="113px">
                  <input type="password" name="password[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="password<?php echo $i;?>" class="input required" placeholder="Enter Password" value="<?php echo $row['password'];?>" style="width:70% !important" /> 
              </td>
              <td width="113px">
                  <input type="password" name="cpass[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="cpass<?php echo $i;?>" equalto="#password<?php echo $i;?>" class="input required" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" value="<?php echo $row['password'];?>" style="width:70% !important" />
              </td>
              <td width="129px">
                  <select name="did[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="did<?php echo $i;?>" class="input validdid chkdid"  style="width:90% !important">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                      <?php

                      global $mysqli;
                      $did_array = array();
                      $query  = "select `id`, `DID` from `did` where account_id='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' and `DID_type` in ('E','X')";
                      $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                      while($row2 = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                      $did_array[$row['id']] = $row['DID'];
                      ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row2['id'];?>" <?php echo $row['did_id']==$row2['id'] ? "selected":"";?>><?php echo $row2['DID'];?></option>
                      <?php }?>
                  </select>

                  <input type="hidden" name="old_didid[<?php echo $i;?>]" value="<?php echo $row['did_id'];?>">
              </td>

          </tr>
      <?php $i++;} ?>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="13">
                  <?php if($cnt<$row3['num_of_lines']){ ?>
                  <span style="float:left; margin:5px"><input type="button" name="add" id="add"  class="btn" value="Add" /></span>
                  <span style="float:left; margin:5px"><a href="<?php echo SITE_URL;?>index.php?view=upload_csv" id="upload_csv" name="upload_csv" class="btn">Upload CSV</a>

                  <?php }if($cnt>1){ ?>
                  <span style="margin-left:5px; float:left; margin:5px"><input type="button" name="remove" id="remove"  class="btnremove" value="Remove" style="display:none" /></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <span style="float:left; margin:5px"><input type="button" name="add" id="add"  class="btn" value="Add" style="display:none"  /></span>
                  <span style="margin-left:5px; float:left; margin:5px"><input type="button" name="remove" id="remove"  class="btnremove" value="Remove" style="display:none"/></span>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
      </table>
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="float:left; margin:00px 10px 10px 30px;"><input type="button" name="save_ext" id="save_ext"  class="btn" value="Save" /></div>
      </form>
  </div>


  <script>
  $(document).on("click", "#save_ext", function () {
      var chk = "0";
      $("#frmextension").validate({
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) { }
      });
      $(".validdid").removeClass("error");  
      $(".extvalue").removeClass("error");
      for(j=0;j<=$(".validdid").length;j++)
      {
          for(i=j+1;i<=$(".validdid").length;i++)
          {
              /* ---- for DID ---- */
              if(($("#did"+i).val() == $("#did"+j).val()) && (i>1)) 
              {
                  if($("#did"+i).val()!="")
                  {
                      $("#did"+i).removeClass("valid");
                      $("#did"+i).addClass("error");
                      chk = "1";
                  }
              }

              /* ---- for EXTENSION ---- */
              if(($("#ext"+i).val() == $("#ext"+j).val()) && (i>1)) 
              {
                  if($("#ext"+i).val()!="")
                  {
                      $("#ext"+i).removeClass("valid");
                      $("#ext"+i).addClass("error");
                      chk = "1";
                  }
              }

          }
      }
      if(chk=="1"){return false;}
      else{
          $("#frmextension").submit();
      }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Try changing the `<input type="button">` to  `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: @Alorika not working

Comment: do you see any errors? is the click callback function being called?

Comment: @Venugopal no errors shown

Comment: is the click callback function being called? can you try to debug it using `alert` or `console.log`

Comment: @Venugopal No its not called